# in presence of smartctrl errors, find is taking 'forever', issues input/output error

Tags: linux, find

How can the find command be sped up? all I seek is an complete-as-possible directory listing with problematic files thus annotated.

I've an old IDE hdd from 2002 with 156GB of data in it's one EXT3 partition. I labeled several years ago as having smartctrl errors. I no longer have a motherboard with IDE ports, and smartctrl is not working with my IDE-to-USB adapter.

My aim is to trash the drive. Before doing that, I'd like to confirm (via comparison of hashes) that the files on the failing drive are on another healthy drive (copied over years ago when both with error-free)

So far, out of 63404 files, 348 are leading to input/output errors. 1/2 percent. I am happy to blindly get rid of those.

UPDATE: took about 5 hours for find to finish. It found 115000 files, 800 of which had input/output errors.

Comment: Have you tried an IDE-SATA adapter? I have found they work very well, without performance loss. They will eliminate the communication errors which sometimes occur in IDE-USB adapters, but they will not of course improve hard errors on the disc itself. @djsmiley2k's advice is excellent: in your case the problem with `find` is that the same sectors (good or bad) can be read again and again while traversing the directory tree, whereas producing an image will read sectors only once.

Comment: I'd buy one if I knew for certain that smartctrl could access the drive. I'd buy it because I also have a dozen seemingly healthy drives I need to assess.  I'd prefer an IDE to eSATA adapter (in case you have particular suggestions).  Can the bad sectors be taken out of service? If so, would I also lose files that are currently without errors?

Comment: I have one installed in a live machine. It's running Windows 10, and I can't easily check if `smartctl` (assuming that's the program you mean) runs, but `CrystalDiskInfo` is able to access all the SMART data. My StarTech adapter from Amazon is to SATA, not eSATA, and it has performed faultlessly for the last 2½ years.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you refer to this drive as "an old IDE HDD" from at least "years ago" leads me to assume that it has very limited storage capacity compared to modern drives. (Edit: You edited the question to say 156 GB. That's definitely small by today's standards.)

`find` is likely not issuing I/O errors; it might possibly be *reporting* them. The errors are coming from the kernel, which is responding to problems reported by the drive.

**Assuming that you have sufficient free space to make an image of the drive, the best approach is probably to use `ddrescue` to do so.**

`ddrescue` is meant specifically to handle marginal media, and does so significantly better than the old workhorse `dd` even when the latter is used with for example `conv=noerror`. There are two big things that ddrescue does better than `dd`:

- **It ensures that data locations don't change.** If a block of data is in one location on the source, and is readable, it will be placed in the same location on the target. This means that things like file system offsets don't change, ensuring that the data that *is* readable remains consistent.
- **It starts off reading large chunks, noting where there are problems,** and then goes back and reads (and writes) whatever problematic areas it found. For marginal source media, this gives you an image containing *most* data within the first pass, and for each successive pass, it gets more and more complete.

It also has a nice progress display, but you can get that from `dd` too.

None of this relies on S.M.A.R.T. data.

Once you have an image of the drive (or all of its partitions), it/they can be mounted in loopback fashion for further analysis and data extraction. As this drive has only a single partition, **the easiest approach may be to simply image that partition,** as it avoids having to deal with loopback device offsets and such things. You could even make an additional copy, keep one in case you mess up and try to get the other into shape by runing `e2fsck` on it. Doing so should give you access to the data with minimal collateral damage, although some parts of the file system are likely to be inaccessible due to damage to file system metadata.

Comment: 156GB of data over USB2.0.  Space on a destination is not an issue. I use dd about once every month or two. New to ddrescue.

Comment: Mfr date: Dec 7th, 2002

Comment: @Jeff I would definitely recommend making an image using ddrescue, then working with that. It's likely to have some file system corruption due to the unreadable blocks, but a simple fsck afterwards should get it into working condition with limited collateral damage.

Comment: I'm reading up on gddrescue now, while find is cranking away. 82000 files so far, 0.5%  have errors.

Comment: http://www.toad.com/gnu/sysadmin/index.html#ddrescue

Answer (score 1):

Smart errors indicate the drive is bad, that is likely why the find is taking so long.

The drive is possibly physically damaged, there's no sensible way you can speed up the find command. Instead, consider using a recover tool to recover an image of the damaged disk, then mount and find the files on this.